# How to return 0 if null from UDF in Snowflake

Tags: function, null, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I am writing user defined functions in Snowflake and doing some SELECT in the functions. I need to return 0 if select returns NULL.

In the below example if there is no rid available from tableA, function is returning NULL, but i need my function to return 0 instead of NULL.

Also, how to declare a variable inside function in snowflake?

Eg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A(ID int)
RETURNS float(53)
AS 
$$
         
        SELECT rid from tableA;
$$
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning 0:

SELECT nvl(rid,0) from tableA;

To use variables you would need to write javascript UDFs rather than sql UDFs

Comment: You can use variables in SQL UDFs.

Comment: @GregPavlik - you can use a variable within a SQL UDF but you can’t declare it within the function, as far as I'm aware. Happy to be proved wrong, though: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-scalar-functions.html#using-sql-variables-in-a-udf

Comment: Yes, I missed the "inside" part of the ask for variables. They have to be passed in as a function parameter.